# Wrote code to copy pictures from one folder to another but destination folder is empty

Tags: python, path, copy

I've wrote this code to search through a text file filled with a number on each line and then search a folder for images that start with that number and copy that picture to another folder. However nothing is being copied over.

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

File_object = open("IDs.txt",'r')
List =  File_object.readlines()

path = 'C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive - name\\Documents\\SearchandCopy'
src_dir = "C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive - name\\Documents\\SearchandCopy\\Search"
dst_dir = "C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive - name\\Documents\\SearchandCopy\\Copy"

for i in range(0, len(List), 1):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.startswith(List[i]):
            shutil.copy(src_dir,dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried this with a number on each line of the text file the list contained `['1\n', '2\n', '3']`

You also need to put full path of the file to copy like this

```
shutil.copy(src_dir + "\\" + file, dst_dir)
```

Also need to look for the file in the src_dir I assume

```
    for file in os.listdir(src_dir): # Instead of path
```

Full code here (will need to change your file paths back)

```
import shutil
import os
import glob

File_object = open("C:\\Users\\Vinnie\\Desktop\\test\\SearchAndCopy\\IDs.txt", 'r')
List = File_object.readlines()
NewList = []
for x in List:
    NewList.append(x.replace('\n', ''))

path = 'C:\\Users\\Vinnie\\Desktop\\test\\SearchAndCopy'
src_dir = "C:\\Users\\Vinnie\\Desktop\\test\\SearchAndCopy\\Search"
dst_dir = "C:\\Users\\Vinnie\\Desktop\\test\\SearchAndCopy\\Copy"


print(List)
print(NewList)
for i in range(0, len(NewList), 1):
    for file in os.listdir(src_dir):            
        if file.startswith(NewList[i]):               
            shutil.copy(src_dir + "\\" + file, dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling:

```py
shutil.copy(src_dir, dst_dir)
```

However, I believe you want to copy the file, not the source directory. In that case, replace that line with:

```py
shutil.copy(file, dst_dir)
```

Comment: Yes you're right, I do only want to copy the files, so I've changed that. I should prob change ```for file in os.listdir(path):``` to ```for file in os.listdir(src_dir):``` then right?